# How to set an Image as title in react-navigation header on android?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to use an image as a title for my header in a StackNavigator. It works fine on ios, but can't get it to work on Android:

```
    const navigationOptions = {
    header: ({navigate}) => ({
        left: (
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={1}
                onPress={() => navigate('DrawerOpen')}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.app_drawer}
                    source={require("../assets/ic_drawer.png")}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        title: (
            <Image
                style={styles.app_logo}
                source={require("../assets/ctw_logo_white.png")}/>
        ),
        style: {backgroundColor: colors.purple},
    }),
};

const Stack = {
    [strings.route_cases]: {
        name: "Cases",
        screen: Object.assign(MainScreen, {navigationOptions}),
    },
    [strings.route_case_details]: {
        name: "Case Details",
        screen: CaseDetailsScreen,
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,,,,

```
  const navigationOptions = {
        header: ({navigate}) => ({
            left: (
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={1}
                    onPress={() => navigate('DrawerOpen')}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.app_drawer}
                        source={require("../assets/ic_drawer.png")}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>

               <Image
            style={styles.app_logo}
            source={require("../assets/ctw_logo_white.png")}/>
</View>
            ),
            title: null,
            style: {backgroundColor: colors.purple},
        }),
    };

    const Stack = {
        [strings.route_cases]: {
            name: "Cases",
            screen: Object.assign(MainScreen, {navigationOptions}),
        },
        [strings.route_case_details]: {
            name: "Case Details",
            screen: CaseDetailsScreen,
        },
    };
```

give marginleft to image and adjust it

Answer (score 0):

The reason the image didn't show was I didn't provide any width to the image, as soon as I specified a width(not just the height) the image appeared on android... Also I had to dynamically adjust the image to display exactly in the centre of the toolbar.